# vector vector string fixed size

Tags: c++

How can i declare such a vector, something like this `vector<vector<string>>vec(1)(2)` for the usage of `vec[0][0]` and `vec[0][1]` without using dinamic sizes with `push_back`.

Comment: The size of an `std::vector` can expand at run-time, and does not work as a multidimensional array. Nesting two vectors would give you freedom to have sub-vectors of different sizes for each dimension, which is probably not what you want. Take a look at [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html), perhaps it will help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using namespace std;
array< array< string, 2 >, 1 > vec;
```

`std::vector` is for dynamic size arrays.
`std::array` (C++11, or use Boost library) is for fixed size arrays.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<std::vector<string>> vec(1, std::vector<string>(2));
```

Then you can access `vec[0][0]` and `vec[0][1]`. (You can change the size of the vector though).